# exclude a meta_key from replace query for all meta_value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**I have to change the word $15 in all meta_value except 1 meta_key name : pricing_tier**

```
UPDATE postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '$15', '$10');
```

I couldn't find anyway to **exclude** *pricing_tier ACF field* from the query.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the result you want that does not change? $10?